# How to get content from a JSP URL using Java

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to get the content of a JSP webpage hosted on a website using Java.
So far, using `HttpURLConnection`, I was only able to retrieve the basic HTML of the page and not the actual data generated by the JSP.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The JSP is processed and the resultant HTML is emitted. Are you trying to get the actual JSP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In website that are using `frame` element, you have to select the URL that the `frame` is pointing to and not the URL in the browser address bar.

So `HttpURLConnection` was doing his job just fine.